# An issue about the ezplot of MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graphics

I use the MATLAB built-in `ezplot` to draw the graph of a parametric equation. For instance,

```
ezplot('sin(t)+2*cos(t)','3*sin(t)+cos(t)',[0,2*pi])
```

> [image]

Now, I replace this expression with the following code:

```
a=1;
b=2;
c=3;
ezplot('a*sin(t)+b*cos(t)','c*sin(t)+cos(t)',[0,2*pi])
```

> [image]

I don't kown how to deal with this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing strings, pass a function handle. In this case a,b and c will be evaluated:

```
a=1;
b=2;
c=3;
ezplot(@(t)a*sin(t)+b*cos(t),@(t)c*sin(t)+cos(t),[0,2*pi])
```

Comment: THX a lot! like your solution:)

Answer (score 5):

that is because MATLAB does not now that the `'a'` in the string you defined is the variable called `a`.

My recommendation: if you want to go changing the equations, change it using string replacement tenciques, or string concatenation techniques.

e.g. `ezplot([num2str(a), '+', num2str(b),'*cos(t)'],......)`

Comment: For integer values this solution is fine, but be aware that it cut's off after the fourth decimal, lowering the precision.

Comment: @Daniel true, if `num2str` is used like shown, but one can also specify the precision as an input. I like your answer more though ;).